# Heapsort Error during runtime

Tags: runtime-error, heapsort

Here is a heapsort program I've created in Java, but I'm having an issue where it won't run.

I'm not getting any errors during compilation, which made the error hard to identify, but if I comment out the size decrement in my extract maximum function the program will run, so I assume that's where the error is. Unfortunately, that line is crucial to the program functioning properly.

If there's anything simple causing this problem, or if major adjustments need to be made to the program, I'd like to know either way.

All input is welcome.

**Update**
added main function.
Code can now be copy-and-pasted to run.

public class Heap
{

```
private int [] data;
private int [] fin;
private int size;
private int tmp = 0;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Heap
 */
public Heap(int[] A)
{
    data = A;
    size = data.length;
    fin = new int [size];
    this.buildHeap(0);
    for(int n = size - 1; n >= 0; n--)
    {
        fin[n] = this.extractMax();
    }
}

public int getSize()
{
    return size;
}

private void setSize(int i)
{
    size = i;
}

public void print()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < this.getSize(); i++)
    System.out.printf("%d\n", fin[i]);
}

/**
 * build heap using top down method
 *  
 * @param  i   the index of the node being built upon
 */
private void buildHeap(int i)
{
    if(i <= (size - 2)/2)
    {
        buildHeap(2*i + 1);
        buildHeap(2*i + 2);
        heapify(i);
    }
}

/**
 * Extract maximum number
 * 
 * @return maximum number of heap
 */
private int extractMax()
{
    int n = size;
    int store = 0;
    store = data[0];
    data[0] = data[n - 1];
    size--;
    this.heapify(0);
    return store;
}

/**
 * Heapify array
 * 
 * @param  i  the index to heapify upon
 */
private void heapify(int i)
{
    if(2*i + 1 < size && data[2*i + 1] > data[i])
    {
        if(2*i + 2 < size && data[2*i + 2] > data[2*i + 1])
        {
            this.exchange(i, 2*i + 2);
            heapify(2*i + 2);
        }
        else
        {
            this.exchange(i, 2*i + 1);
            heapify(2*i + 1);
        }
    }
    if(2*i + 2 < size && data[2*i + 2] > data[i])
    {
        this.exchange(i, 2*i + 2);
        heapify(2*i + 2);
    }
}

private boolean exchange(int i, int k)
{
    tmp = data[i];
    data[i] = data[k];
    data[k] = tmp;
    return true;
}

public static void main(String [] args)
{
    int [] arr = {5,13,2,25,7,17,20,8,4};
    Heap heapsort = new Heap(arr);
    heapsort.print();
}
```

}

Comment: Could you post the stack-trace of your error?

Comment: Part of the issue I'm having is that I'm not getting an error report, yet the program won't run.

Comment: You mean `size--` prevents program from running?

Comment: If I remove that bit of code the program will run, yes. It just won't run properly.

Comment: And if you do not remove it...? what happens?

Comment: Basically nothing. When I run the program with command line it does absolutely nothing, or that's the way it seems at least.

Comment: Could you update your post with all of your code (including `imports` and `main` function), so just can copy-paste-run?